# Audio streaming with React native

Tags: audio, react-native, streaming

I need to develop an app for a client that streams audio files from the network (both Android and iOS). I plan to use react-native-audio-streaming component. Clients biggest concern is that streamed files are not stored locally. Does anyone know is that the case with react-native-audio-streaming?

Comment: I used react-native-audio-streaming but none of the file was stored locally..

Comment: react-native-video is the coolest of all...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this npm module. It will stream the audio/video using  the inbuilt player on the device.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-native-video-player

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`react-native-audio-streamer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-audio-streamer) to stream the audios. It works on both iOS & Android. And is very easy to use. Moreover it has got built in functions to handle interruptions, for example to pause the audio you just have  to call this function`RNAudioStreamer.pause()`and to play it back call `RNAudioStreamer.play()`.

Good luck.

Comment: Can it does a 2x speed?